# How can i download style with xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have problem with download style,exactly Color  style.
I tried download it with xpath,before i use Curl for download website.
I would like get color from this website:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/talking-ginger/9nblggh0c0j7
I need orange(#d1480e) and gray(#d2d2d2) colors from stars. How can i do it ??

I tried that  :

```
$x=$xpath->query("//*[@class='icon-star']");

 var_dump( $x->getAttribute('style'));
```

Comment: you don't "download" with xpath. xpath is for querying a DOM. the download is done entirely separately.

Comment: and if you'll note, there's no style attribute on the tags you're finding: `<li><i class="icon-star"></i></li>`.

Comment: I know before xpath i used Curl.

Comment: It's not xpath's job to deal with styles. xpath deals with DOM, not css. download the css and parse it with some other tool.

Comment: Ok ,do you know some tools for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said, XPath is not for parsing CSS; it's only for selecting nodes from XML (or HTML) trees. At best, you'll get the `<style>` element, but can't do anything with the individual CSS styles.

A tool for parsing and selecting the styles themselves would be CSSParser or [its PHP implemention](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser).